# Whats wrong with backbone this time?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlayersRouter' of undefined

I did everything the same like allways, but what's now happening? Here is my path:

$rails new infinity
$cd infinity
gem "rails-backbone"
$bundle install
rails g backbone:install
rails g scaffold Player stat:integer health:integer strength:integer
rake db:migrate
rails g backbone:scaffold Player stat:integer health:integer strength:integer

Views/players/index.html.erb

```
<div id="players"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
window.router = new Infinity.Routers.PlayersRouter({players: <%= @players.to_json.html_safe -%>});
Backbone.history.start();
});
</script>
```

What part of it is wrong? My rails app name? or scaffold name? Its simplest part and like allways im failing :)

My console says:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Player' of undefined player.js?body=1:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Players' of undefined edit_view.js?body=1:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Players' of undefined index_view.js?body=1:7
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Players' of undefined new_view.js?body=1:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Players' of undefined player_view.js?body=1:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Players' of undefined show_view.js?body=1:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'PlayersRouter' of undefined players_router.js?body=1:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlayersRouter' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Infinity` is reserved global property of javascript. It is better to re-consider the rails project name.

Comment: That answer i waited for :) I trough that the problem could be the name, but didnt know which exactly.